# How to improve regex efficiency for profiler

Tags: java, regex, performance

This is a result from a profiler:

> In the view 'destinationDetails', the following
>            regular expression cannot be executed by the system's accelerated
>            regex engine and will be executed with Java's built-in regular
>            expression engine instead:
>
> ```
>  /(?<=dst\s)(.+?)\n/
> ```
>
> In most cases, this incompability occurs because the regular
>   expression contains lookahead/lookbehind constructs like 
>   `\A, \Z, \b, ^, $,  (?=X), (?!X), (?<=X), or (?<!X)`
>
> input source:
>       2011-12-06T00:02:01.726755+05:18 Dec 06 2011 00:00:33 KOC-TEJ-CBA-ASA-5510-3 :  %ASA-4-106023: Deny tcp src
>   CBA:10.2.2.78/1885 dst Outside:10.31.129.2/1494 by access-group
>   "CBA_access_in" [0x8104ddd0, 0x0]

Can someone please explain how to make it more efficient to overcome the profiler warning?

Answer (score 0):

The one element of the regex that stands out as a potential problem, given the warning message examples, is the "zero-width positive lookbehind" `(?<=dst\s)`.  It is used is to ensure that "dst\s" precedes the remainder of the match, yet is not captured as part of the match.

How you replace the `(?<=dst\s)` this depends very much on how the regex as a whole is being used:

- It is really important that `dst\s` is not captured as part of the match?  In short, if you simply want an answer to "does the regex match some input, yes or no" then you likely don't care what's consumed or not.  Try: `/dst\s(.+?)\n/`.
- If this is part of a larger regex, or if you're doing anything more complicated with the regex than the simple "yes/no" match, then that will need to be put forth in order for someone to make any sensible suggestions.

Comment: The reason i am using this regex is , i dont want to capture dst\s. It is very important.